# RabbitMQ Java client: properly close connection on shutdown

Tags: java, rabbitmq

When running the [RabbitMQ Java client](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) in a microservice, I was wondering if you should somehow ensure the connection is shut down properly in case the JVM receives a SIGTERM signal and shuts down? For example, would a shutdown hook like the following make any difference, e.g. allow RabbitMQ to flush its queues?

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
  try {
    connection.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}));
```